# Was gibt es zweimal im Wort "Zwielicht"?

Tags: meaning

Wenn sich das Wort "Zwielicht" auf die Dämmerung bezieht, was gibt es da zweimal, wie es "zwie" andeutet?

Comment: Das i gibt es zweimal im Zwielicht. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Zwielicht* ist gemeint im Sinne von *„weder hell noch dunkel“*, möglicherweise auch *„Licht von Sonne und Mond“*. [Wikipedia meint](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwielicht):

> Zwielicht (altdeutsch für „Licht aus zwei Quellen“) bezeichnet [...] Lichtverhältnisse, die von einer Mischung aus Licht und Dunkelheit erzeugt werden.

Es ist also nicht nur eine Sorte Licht, die diese Lichtverhältnisse erzeugt, sondern eine Mischung aus zwei verschiedenen Lichtverhältnissen.

Answer (score 6):

Im [Duden-Wörterbuch (online)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zwielicht) steht (Hervorhebungen von mir):

> Licht, das durch Mischung von **natürlichem dämmrigem** und **künstlichem** Licht entsteht

Bei *Herkunft* steht, es stamme aus dem Niederdeutschen < mittelniederdeutsch twēlicht, eigentlich = halbes, gespaltenes Licht.

Comment: Verwandt mit "entzweien" oder "zweifel", glaube ich.

Answer (score 5):

According to [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=twilight) it is a cognate with *twilight* (late 14th century) and Dutch *tweelicht* (16th century).

They're not sure about the exact connotation of "twi-", but suspect a meaning of "half" light.

This dictionary also mentions a Middle High German *Zwischerliecht*.

Answer (score 4):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zwielicht) kommt Zwielicht

> aus dem Niederdeutschen < mittelniederdeutsch twēlicht, eigentlich = halbes, gespaltenes Licht

Answer (score 3):

Meine erste Assoziation war nicht "zweimal" sondern "zwiespältig", (noch nicht richtig hell, nicht mehr richtig dunkel) und nicht sozusagen "zwiefältig"("zweifaltig") (also zwei verschiedene Lichtarten/-sorten). (Aber Takkat und splattne haben das erstere ja auch als wahrscheinliche Herkunft bereits aus dem Duden beigebracht)

Answer (score 2):

Es kommt bestimmt von "Zwischenlicht" - zwischen hell und dunkel.